# PySide application Frozen with py2app won't run on Fat32 or Exfat

Tags: python, macos, pyside, py2app

I have a PySide application that I have frozen with py2app. It works great when I run it from a USB drive formatted as Mac OS Extended (Journaled), but will not run when the drive is either Fat32 or ExFat.

I've tested with multiple computers and drives, always works great on Journaled, but errors out on Fat32 and ExFat.

Has anyone experienced this or know how to fix it, I'm stumped.

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of errors do you get?

Comment: @RonaldOussoren com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[156]: (org.pythonmac.unspecified.hellopyside.79584[43449]) Job appears to have crashed: Abort trap: 6